# Find common sequence of elements in list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have list of lists containing Id's as following-

```
[[45, 41, 20, 25, 78],
 [54, 12, 45, 36, 59],
 [45, 12, 45, 41, 88],
 [74, 85, 41, 20, 25],
 [54, 45, 36, 59],
 [74, 20, 25]]
```

Problem 1: I need all the  lists having same prefix(list starting with same number) in one list.
Desired output

```
[[45, 41, 20, 25, 78],
 [45, 12, 45, 41, 88]]
[[54, 12, 45, 36, 59],
 [54, 45, 36, 59]]
[[74, 85, 41, 20, 25],
 [74, 20, 25]]
```

Problem 2: Later find the common elements in respective sub-lists. For example:

```
   [[45, 41, 20, 25, 78],
   [45, 12, 45, 41, 88]]
```

In this list common elements are [45,41]

Final desired output:

```
[[45, 41],
 [54, 45, 36, 59],
 [74, 20, 25]]
```

Comment: I really don't understand how you get to your final output

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have edited the question. Hopefully this would be understandable

Comment: For the first step, iterate over the outer list and put elements (inner lists) in a dict with first number of inner list as key, then the `.values()` is what you want. (Doesn't understand the second step either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` For Problem 1:

```
from itertools import groupby

orig_list = [[45, 41, 20, 25, 78],
 [54, 12, 45, 36, 59],
 [45, 12, 45, 41, 88],
 [74, 85, 41, 20, 25],
 [54, 45, 36, 59],
 [74, 20, 25]]
sorted_list = sorted(orig_list, key=lambda l: l[0])
list1 = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted_list, lambda l:l [0])]
```

Output:

```
[[[45, 41, 20, 25, 78], [45, 12, 45, 41, 88]],
 [[54, 12, 45, 36, 59], [54, 45, 36, 59]],
 [[74, 85, 41, 20, 25], [74, 20, 25]]]
```

---

For Problem 2, you could use *set intersection*; however, it **won't preserve order**:

```
[list(set.intersection(*[set(s) for s in sublists])) for sublists in list1]
```

Output:

```
[[41, 45], [59, 36, 45, 54], [25, 74, 20]]
```

If you want to **preserve order** and there are always 2 sublists, you could try this:

```
[[x for x in sublist[0] if x in sublist[1]] for sublist in list1]
```

Output:

```
[[45, 41], [54, 45, 36, 59], [74, 20, 25]]
```

If it's possible to have other number of sublists (more than 2 or only 1), you can tweak it like this:

```
[[x for x in sublist[0] if all([x in s for s in sublist[1:]])] for sublist in pre_list]
```

Comment: I've updated the answer. It assumes that you don't have more than 2 sublists with the same first element.

Comment: I added another option if there are more than 2 sublists. This also takes care if there is only 1 sublist, which the other one won't handle. So it's a more general approach.

Comment: for problem 2, I have multiple sublists. given code works fine if there is 2 sublists. Could you please help me out in finding common numbers between multiple sublists.

Comment: Does that last line of code in my answer not work? If so, how does it not work? Might be worth updating your question.

Comment: It is fetching common numbers in sublists if there are two sublists but not when dealing with multiple sublists. For example:
[[126, 133],
  [126, 259, 22],
  [126, 136, 55],
  [126, 86, 84, 50],
  [126, 129, 1, 22],
  [126, 86, 12],
  [126, 1, 209],
  [126, 1, 216, 112],
  [126, 86, 45, 79, 45, 79, 63, 63, 234, 234, 234, 169],
  [126, 94, 129],
  [126, 94, 129],
  [126, 86, 84],
  [126, 136, 212, 254, 258]] 
For above list am getting [126] as common number among sublists

Comment: Oh I would have thought that's the output you would have wanted. Are you looking for numbers that appear in at least 2 sublists then? Or what would you expect?

Comment: Yes numbers appearing in more than one sub lists

Comment: You could remove duplicates and use `collections.Counter` to count numbers that appear more than once. Regarding duplicates, I'm assuming you wouldn't count `234` as appearing twice, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is your solution**

```
list1 = [[45, 41, 20, 25, 78],[54, 12, 45, 36, 59],[45, 12, 45, 41, 88],[74, 85, 41, 20, 25],[54, 45, 36, 59],[74, 20, 25]]
converted_list = []
i=0
while i <= (len(list1)/2)+1:
    a = list1.pop(0)
    print(a)
    for j in list1:
        if j[0]==a[0]:
            b = list1.pop(list1.index(j))
            converted_list.append([a,b])
            break
    i+=1
print(converted_list)

final_list = []
for i in converted_list:
    common_list = []
    for j in i[0]:
        if j in i[1]:
            common_list.append(j)
    final_list.append(common_list)
print(final_list)
```